# How to export only Histogram mean to excel from Anylogic?

Tags: excel, anylogic

I'm connecting my excel file to anylogic and it works well when I use kind of data like parameters but I have problems when I want to export only the mean value of a Histogram. The Histogram is a FlowTime of a product.

```
FlowtimeCPNocciole.add((time()-entity.SystemIn)+entity.protime);
```

Can you help me with this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the histogram data object (see image) all you have to do is FlowtimeCPNocciole.mean() and it returns the mean value.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :D I also want to perform multiple runs of the same experiment. Can you please tell me how to do it? I've already tried this:            new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        // stops the model
        getExperiment().stop();
        try {
            // delay
            this.sleep(1000);
        } catch(Exception e) {};
        // runs it again
        ((Simulation) getExperiment()).button.action();
    }
}.start();                                                                                                 but it doesn't work.

Comment: what version of anylogic do you own?

Comment: Anylogic 7.0.2 Professional

Comment: In that case you can program your model to run several instances of the same experiment. The first example of anylogic in three days explains that.

Comment: What if one only has the Learning Version?